# How do I get the email body given an Amazon SES Message ID?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-ses, boto3

I sent a few emails using Amazon SES and I have their Message IDs (as generated by Amazon SES).

Given these Message IDs, I would like to query the Amazon SES API and get the details of the email I sent (i.e., email body, subject, from, to).

How do I go about doing so?

If it helps, I am using the boto3 library for Python.

Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge, SES does not store this information after the email is successfully sent.

Comment: @ceejayoz is correct, that message is not stored by SES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon SES does not store this data, at least not in any way accessible to users (I'd imagine they have an internal audit trail for spam/abuse cases, but it's not exposed in the API).

You'll need to store the data yourself, or use a different third-party sender.

Comment: Mandrill offers this, which was a pretty handy feature, but they've recently changed their TOS in a nasty manner.

Comment: For anyone still looking, Mailgun offers this.